# How to frame bypass doors with metal studs?

Tags: steel, door-frame

I am using metal studs (25ga steel) in my basement for a room. This room will have a closet with two sets of bypass sliding doors. The doors are 30" wide (and fairly heavy) and with a 1" overlap, will require a finished opening of 59" for each set.

My understanding is that the metal studs probably won't support the weight of these doors on a track so I will need to install a 2x4 frame with a header. What size header will I need and how big of an opening should I be leaving to account for the wood framing, header, and probably 3/4" door frames. Anything else I need to consider?

Comment: @Jack I will need to purchase a track kit because I already have the door slabs. They're 2668 (2'6" x 6'8" x 1-3/8") SC 6P SM. I believe this means Solid Core 6-Panel Stock Molded(??). It's something from this company: http://www.macdoors.com/pages/literature/Revised-MaC-Interior-2020-030220.pdf

Comment: Make sure the hardware you order than handle the weight of the door. I typically double the weight capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a rough opening of 61" wide for a wood jamb. This will allow room for 3/4" material and shim space for critical shimming to get it dead straight and plumb. Will need more info for the R.O. height....

When you set your steel track to the floor, cut it so the ends meet the rough opening dimensions. Set the steel studs back 1 1/2" from the ends at the rough opening. A double 2X6 header with a plywood filler should work for practically any door of any weight you choose to use.

Screw the wood jack studs to the steel studs using coarse thread screws Same with the bottom of the jack studs where it sets in the bottom track. Set your header on top of the jacks and screw them in place. Ideally to the jack studs too, but you may need pilot holes to minimize splitting.

Be certain you use the proper set back for the finishes whether you are using wood jambs and casing or going with a simple drywall wrap.

[image]

I don't know how much room your particular bypass hardware takes up, but if you have your doors already and they are 6'8" and your track and roller use another 2" to 2 1/2", you have room for a plate under the joist. Secure it well to the joist that is over it, shimming it flat and level if needed and set the track directly to that. Use 9/16" thick wood trim to cover the track so it flushes up with the drywall once that is installed, then the trim/casing will cover the joint between the head covering and drywall.

The metal studs will be 1/8" wider than the wood plate. Using 9/16" material at the top should allow the 1/2" drywall and wood trim filler to lay flush with one another.

Comment: I may need to shorten the doors because my joist height is really close to 7ft in my basement and i plan to use a drop ceiling

Comment: Then you can add blocking where needed and add a plate... or not... depending on what kind of RO height you need to set the top jamb to. If you add a drop ceiling as in suspended grid and panel, you will need 3" for that so your track may be inset in the ceiling, and the jamb/trim is what the wall track will mount to. Is the path the door travels with the joists or perpendicular?

Comment: Parallel with the joists although it just happens to pretty much line up with one. I can adjust it still

Comment: I added more to the answer above, it may need a little more clarification